# JQuery Smooth Scroll With Specific Offset on Mobile

Tags: jquery, html, css, smooth-scrolling

I am using the following jquery script to achieve the smooth scroll effect on a website that I am creating:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('a[href^="#"]').on('click',function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var target = this.hash,
    $target = $(target);

    $('html, body').stop().animate({
        'scrollTop': $target.offset().top-140
    }, 900, 'swing', function () {
        window.location.hash = target;
    });
}); 
});
```

As can be seen, I am adding a padding on the offset (.offset().top-140) due to a sticky nav bar that I am implementing. However, on the mobile version, the padding is too much. How can I go about on changing the padding when it comes to the mobile version? Thank you!

Comment: Instead of hard-coding `140`, what if you fetched the current height of the nav bar and subtracted that amount instead?

Comment: Thank you so much! I wasn't aware that one was able to fetch the height of an element through .height(). It worked! @TylerRoper